# How to check variance with GARCH (1,1) model?

Tags: r, garch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Heteroscedastic test does not solve the problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/heteroscedastic-test-does-not-solve-the-problem)

I have two list with around 700 daily prices(each) I would use a garch (1,1) model and check if the variance is constant during all the period, how could I do?

Thanks