# Can (log-)likelihood be used to compare a binomial model to its beta-binomial equivalent?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio, likelihood, beta-binomial-distribution

In [this article](https://rpubs.com/cakapourani/beta-binomial) the author talks about fitting beta-binomial models to data when the there data is over-dispersed relative to the assumptions of a model with binomial errors. Near the end they present two options for testing whether the additional parameter accounting for the over-dispersion is necessary.

One of these options is:

[image]

However, from what I have read about likelihood theory, you can't compare likelihoods when the underlying distribution is different (see [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345069/likelihood-comparable-across-different-distributions)).

Can you use likelihood to compare these two distributions if all else is held constant?

I have googled around and searched this site but I can't seem to find any answers on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood ratio test supposes *nested hypothesis*, that is, the smaller model is a special case of the larger model. And, **that is the case for the binomial and beta-binomial models**.

See [parametrizations for the beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Alternative_parametrizations), you could reparametrize the beta binomial distribution using the mean/variance parametrization for the beta distribution, and then you recover the binomial distribution by letting the beta variance be zero.